# Coverage report for jest unit tests not displaying with --coverage option

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, create-react-app, react-scripts

My Project is based on Create-react-app setup and my package.json script for testing unit tests is as below

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "react-scripts test --coverage",
 }
```

or

```
 "test": "react-scripts test --coverage --collectCoverageFrom=src/**/*.{js,jsx}
```

It executes tests in **Test** folder but doesn't display coverage report.Can you help to solve this issue.
[image]

My file structure is as below 
src
|
--- **Test**
---components> moduleA > package1 > package2> transaction.js, abcd.js... etc

ProcessEvent.test.js

```
describe('ProcessEvent Component', () => {

    const expectedProps = {
        "event": {iconStatus:'active', desc:'abc'}
    }

    it('should render without error', () => {
        const component = <ProcessEvent {...expectedProps}/>
        const wrapper = component.find('.eventclass');
        expect(wrapper.length).toBe(1);
    });

    it('should receive valid props', () => {
        const component = shallow(<ProcessEvent {...expectedProps}/>);
        const wrapper = component.find('.eventclass');
        expect(component.props).toBeDefined();
    });

});
```

Comment: Can you post some examples of your tests?  Could you try running your tests directly with jest?  i.e. "jest --coverage"

Comment: Hi @dyouberg, to use "jest --coverage" I will have to eject out of create-react-app setup, which I dont want to do. Now it says 'jest can not parse file'

Comment: Ok, fair enough.  It looks like the coverage utility is running correctly, could you post examples of your tests?  Maybe that's where the problem is

Comment: I have added my ProcessEvent.test.js component I have similar 3 other test components.

Answer (score 2):

Using `--watchAll=false` parameter makes it list down all the files.

Example package.json

```
{
...
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test",
    "coverage": "react-app-rewired test -- --coverage --watchAll=false",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "serve": "node server.js"
  },
...
}
```

Also your coverage report is physically located at /coverage/lcov-report. Opening an index.html located there, would show you the coverage report in your browser.

Comment: I was facing this kind of issue too using `--watchAll=false` did print out the result on my console put the generated report was still showing empty... do you have any idea what will be causing it?